# Is there a possible way to get a string from the keyboard and print it?

Tags: assembly, keyboard, nasm, x86-16, 16-bit

I'm trying to make a program that reads a string from the keyboard, and then prints the string. I tried doing so, and it decided to only print the first letter. For example:

**What it was supposed to do:**

Type in string, prints string.

**What it did:**

Type in string, prints s.

Does anyone have any ideas to resolve this issue? Or does anyone know how to fix this bug?

***Using compiler NASM with 16-bit code.***

Comment: Short on details. Is this under DOS, do you want to use the BIOS etc? If this is DOS, INT [21h Function 0Ah which is DOS buffered input](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm). You can use [INT 21h/AH=9h to print a string](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) but you have to terminate it with a `$` instead of 00h.

Comment: Michael Petch I'll try that.

Comment: Please don't morph your question into something else after you received an answer. If you post a new question with what you had edited, I will provide an answer. Your new question is answerable.

Comment: *Is there a possible way* - if you've ever seen any program do something, you already know it's possible.  Obviously the answer is "yes".  More useful phrasing would be to ask how, and/or how hard or complicated it is.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch) for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65515276/is-there-a-possible-way-to-get-a-string-from-the-keyboard-and-print-it/65515430#comment115829062_65515276). This did work:

```
MOV DX, [STRING]
MOV AH, 0Ah
INT 0x21
```

Comment: AH=0Ah wants a pointer in DX.  This loads a value into DX from memory, rather than setting DX=address of a symbol.  Normally you don't need to store pointers in static storage, if your array itself is in static storage or on the stack.